# Import pom's value into weblogic.xml

Tags: maven-2, weblogic, pom.xml

I have `pom.xml` that contains defined values. I would like to use one of them in `weblogic.xml` file in WAR like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <context-root>someContext</context-root>

    <virtual-directory-mapping>
        <local-path>${foo}</local-path>
        <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>
    </virtual-directory-mapping>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

But after building my application, it does not put there this `foo` variable.

Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly enable filtering in the war plugin for this to work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>WEB-INF/weblogic.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```